# Monitor Amazon EC2 API requests in Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm unable to pull Amazon Cloudwatch metrics in an EC2 instance with Grafana. The setup is the following:

EC2 instance with Grafana:

- Security group: (ssh,tpc,22,0.0.0.0/0;custom tcp,tpc,3000,0.0.0.0/0;)
- Policy attached to the role in the EC2 instance with Grafana:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadingMetricsFromCloudWatch",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmHistory",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadingLogsFromCloudWatch",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:GetLogGroupFields",
                "logs:StartQuery",
                "logs:StopQuery",
                "logs:GetQueryResults",
                "logs:GetLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadingTagsInstancesRegionsFromEC2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeRegions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadingResourcesForTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "tag:GetResources",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Grafana query screenshot without retrieving any data:

[image: Grafana query]

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/monitor.html

> This is an opt-in feature. To enable this feature for your AWS account, contact AWS Support.

1. Are you sure you have enabled this feature for your AWS account?
2. Are you sure that `InstanceId` is the right dimension and that only one
   dimension is required?

The best option is to go to the AWS CloudWatch console and generate graph there. Then you can compare generated CloudWatch query with the CloudWatch query generated by Grafana.

Comment: Hey Jan, not sure whether it was because of the opt-in feature or because the instance is an Elasticbeanstalk, but it was confusing to me since I can see EC2 instances along with the Elasticbeanstalk and I thought I could use that namespace as explained in my answer and this was wrong

Answer (score 0):

I finally could pull some data by changing the namespace to AWS/ElasticBeanstalk and the Dimensions with EnvironmentName to the one I want to target. Before I had to go to the configuration dashboard of the Elasticbeanstalk and add the proper metrics in the CloudWatch Custom Metric in the input select